# Invalid XMlRoot Element

Tags: c#, xml

My output of xml should be like this

```
<ns1:customerApplication
     soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
     xmlns:ns1="urn:">
```

I added xmlRoot

```
[XmlRoot("ns:customerApplication ")]
public class customerApplication     
{
}
```

But i am getting like this

```
  <ns_x003A_CustomerApplication xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    </ns_x003A__CustomerApplication>
```

How to change `ns_x003A_CustomerApplication` to `ns:CustomerApplication`

please help

thanks
supriya

Comment: The "ns1" part of your xml element name is actually a xml namespace qualifier, which is a shortcut for the real namespace.  Can you provide us with what the namespace is? It should be in one of the parent elements of where your CustomerApplication element is.  It usually looks like `<... xmlns:ns1="http://something.com" ...>`

Answer (score 1):

You specifying element name only and as result it had to escape ":" to something that is accepted as element name - *x003A*_ (hex-encoded code of ":").

You need to specify namespace and node name as shown in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "www.contoso.com", 
  ElementName = "MyGroupName")]
 public class Group ...
```